# Does Torna have missable quests?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2, xenoblade-2-torna-golden-country

*Xenoblade Chronicles 2* had side-quests you could permanently miss by advancing the main story. Does the expansion *Torna ~ The Golden Country* also have side-quests you can permanently miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After completing the main story, I can confirm there are no missable quests in *Torna ~ The Golden Country*. The main story has a point of no return, but the game saves before that point.

According to ziltama [on GameSpot](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/204208-xenoblade-chronicles-2/77121167), while no quests are missable, there are items you only get once which can be sold or missed .

> Technically, there are missables in the game: If you accidentally sell one time items or have your inventory full when you’re supposed to get one.
>
> The only one time per save file unique item is Master Scope in new game plus after completing Lora’s 2nd chart.
>
> There are more that are one time per playthrough. If you want more, then you have to do another playthrough. This includes common tiered burst symbols and legendary tiered crystal earrings.